# calculate size of sql azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I calculate the current size of a SQL Azure Database? (Not the maximum size limit)

Several places ([like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/10/10048453.aspx)) suggest using this sql:

```
SELECT SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8192
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

However when executing this as the Administrator login I get this error:

```
Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Comment: GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO database_user;

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is probably because you're running the query on the **master** database. If you're using SQL Server Management Studio, choose your database first (not the master database), and execute the query. This should work. Oh and by the way, if you want the size in megabytes, try the following:

```
SELECT (SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8192) / 1024 / 1024 AS DbSizeInMB
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

**OR**
You can check your database size and its usage through Windows Azure Management Portal also.
[image]

**Source:** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/

Comment: official reference page from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394114.aspx

Comment: I am using the migration wizard from codeplex to move my SQL db to Azure https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/ and the `usage overview` is not available. because the db is so new, so I used your query which works great. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note: (reserved_page_count * 8192) is size in kilobytes, so convert it to MB would be just (reserved_page_count * 8192) / 1024. Your query would return size in GB.

Comment: @avs099 the official reference page has now moved to [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/)