# How can i get the database_size value of sp_spaceused?

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I'm trying to get the database_size value of SQL Server (Data Warehouse)

As far as i know, we have sp_spaceused that can be used to check database_size

But i couldn't find any solution to help grep the number of database_size value

Another solution is not using spaceused, but since Azure DWH doesn't allow sys.master_file, other solution also didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look into this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014392/select-sql-server-database-size it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Suraj.I'll check it

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the answers mentioned using sys.master_file which is not allowed in my case.

Comment: Try this thread also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296150/calculate-size-of-sql-azure-database

Comment: Oops, Catalog view 'dm_db_partition_stats' is not supported in this version. '((

Comment: Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql), `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` is called `sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats` in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

When you will run the query `EXEC sp_helpdb` you will get the entire database size. Here also you can pass any specific database name. No matter in which database you are currently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion, and got this error
Stored procedure sp_helpdb does not exist or is not supported.
I guess Azure DWH is pretty limited in term of what we can do :(

Comment: That might be some limitation and I have checked in the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of DMVs you can use to get this kind of information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-file-space-usage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
declare @dbsize as bigint
declare @logsize as bigint

select 
  @dbsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 = 0 then size else 0 end))
, @logsize = sum(convert(bigint,case when status & 64 <> 0 then size else 0 end))
from dbo.sysfiles;

select dbSizeInMB = cast((@dbsize + @logsize)*8/1024.0  AS decimal(10,2) );
```

Comment: It said: Catalog view 'sysfiles' is not supported in this version